# Flask - Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown doesn't work on sub page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, bootstrap-4

I have a working navbar with a dropdown link in base.html. The dropdown will work on any page, except those under certain sub-pages.

Works:

- index/
- dashboard/
- users/user123/

Doesn't work (clicking "Dropdown Menu" doesn't do anything):

- projects/project_a/project_1

Navbar code:

```
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="myDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     Dropdown Menu
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="myDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('main_bp.option_1_page') }}">Option 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('main_bp.option_2_page') }}">Option 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

There are a few posted issues that seem to have the same problem, but did not solve this issue. Things I've tried:

- Verified that bootstrap is rendering on sub-pages in question (inspect > network > js)
- Removing the href="#" in my navbar code
- Confirmed that when hovering over the "Dropdown Menu" navbar link, the url is the same on all pages

I use the `url_for` pattern throughout my code, so my hunch is that it's not a path issue (although I guess it could be). It looks something like `/current_page#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

- In the pages that were **not** rendering the dropdown, I called `{{ super() }}` twice in the scripts block. Removing one of them results in the dropdown working properly.
- I can reproduce the error in previously working pages by adding an additional `{{ super() }}` call

I have a basic understanding of super(), but if anyone can point out why calling it twice would have this effect it would be interesting to hear.

Answer (score 0):

add bootstrap.min.js and popper.min.js lib in your project

```
        ex:
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have bootstrap, and I'm not sure why I would need popper if the dropdown already renders on other pages